# Comment « dépit » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « sans tenir compte de » ?

Tags: étymologie

Je cite [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%c3%a9pit/23790?q=en+depit+de#23666).

> Irritation légère causée par une déception, une blessure d'amour-propre, amertume, rancœur passagère ; désappointement
>
> **En dépit de quelque chose**, malgré cela, sans en tenir compte. [Cette définition [égale celle sur Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_d%C3%A9pit_de)

et Etymonline sur [despite (n., prep.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/despite)

> c. 1300, *despit* (n.) "contemptuous challenge, defiance; act designed to insult or humiliate someone;" mid-14c., "scorn, contempt,"
>   from Old French *despit* (12c., Modern French *dépit*),
>   from Latin *despectus* "a looking down on, scorn, contempt,"        from past participle of *despicere* "look down on, scorn,"
>   from *de* "down" (see [de-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/de-?ref=etymonline_crossreference))
>   + *spicere/specere* "to look at" (from PIE root [*spek-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*spek-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to observe").
>
> The prepositional sense "notwithstanding" (early 15c.) is short for in despite of "in defiance or contempt of" (c. 1300), a loan-translation of Anglo-French *en despit de* "in contempt of."

1. Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « amertume, rancœur » avec « sans tenir compte de  » ?
2. « amertume, rancœur » ne contradisent-ils pas  « sans tenir compte de  » ? Si quelque chose dépite soi, on en tiennent compte évidemment. E.g. la consommation de viande dépite les végans, et ceux qui protestent contre elle assurément   tiennent compte de la consommation de viande.

Comment: I find it difficult to get my head around your questions.  What notions sous-tendent X with Y is not very clear.  Wiktionary entries can be ok, they're usually a bit of a mess and subpar.  Taking bits out of two different definitions and asking how we go from one to the other is not the way to deal with issues of etymology and change in meaning over the course of time.

Answer (score 7):

1. Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « amertume, rancœur » avec « sans tenir compte de »

Le mépris, qui est le sens original de *despit* en français.

Celui qui est dépité, c'est celui qui était méprisé, regardé de haut par quelqu'un d'autre (honteux). Ce sens s'est atténué au fil des siècles.

« En dépit de » signifie « sans tenir compte », c'est à dire « en méprisant », « au mépris ».

> Samedi dernier, elle a décidé d'accoster à Lampedusa en Sicile, en dépit de l'interdiction des autorités italiennes.

est sensiblement équivalent à :

> ... au mépris de l'interdiction des autorités italiennes.

---

2. « amertume, rancœur » ne contredisent-ils pas « sans tenir compte de » ?

Non. L'amertume est toujours présente dans *en dépit de*.
Le dépit, l'amertume présents dans l'expression figée *en dépit de* ont conservé leurs sens. *Dépit* dans ses autres usages s'est éloigné mais n'est pas contradictoire.

- Si quelque chose dépite soi, on en tiennent compte évidemment.

J'imagine qu'il faut comprendre: *Si quelque chose nous dépite, on en tient évidemment compte.*

La réponse est : Non, on en tient compte ou pas.

> E.g. la consommation de viande dépite les végans, et ceux qui protestent contre elle assurément tiennent compte de la consommation de viande.

Ce n'est pas le verbe que j'aurai choisi. Le sentiment d'un vegan vis a vis de la consommation de viande est très éloigné de ce qu'on peut décrire comme une *irritation légère et passagère*.

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne pige pas encore comment * despit* s'est atténué à signifier « sans tenir compte ».  J'ai remanié la question 2.

Comment: *Despit* ne s'est pas atténué dans l'expression *en dépit de* car *dépit* y a conservé son sens de mépris. Ta question 2 est toujours incompréhensible.

Comment: J'ai réécrit ma question 2. Est-elle mieux ?

Comment: Non, c'est toujours obscur.

Answer (score -2):

Je crois qu'il est important de d'abord distinguer le mot *dépit*, pris isolément et signifiant isolément comme détaillé plus haut des locutions dans lesquelles ce mot est employé, les plus fréquentes :

- **de** dépit
- **par** dépit
- **en** dépit **de**

Si les deux premières reprennent certainement le sens d'irritation ou de rancune porté par le mot seul, c'est encore à dire un affect dont seul un humain est capable, la dernière peut (**aujourd'hui**) s'employer relativement à toute sorte de phénomène c'est encore à dire de façon dénuée de tout affect et, de ce fait, effectivement, rigoureusement exempte de toute idée d'amertume ou de rancœur.

À la différence des deux autres, *en dépit de* s'est grammaticalisée pour devenir une préposition spécifiquement réservée à l'expression de la concession.

**aujourd'hui** car... ce ne fut pas toujours le cas.

Voltaire critique le :

*"Et je m'ose assurer qu'en dépit de mon crime
Mon sang leur servira d'assez pure victime"*

de Corneille, en ces termes :

*"On ne peut pas dire en dépit de mon crime comme on dit malgré mon crime quel qu'ait été mon crime, car un crime n'a point de dépit. On dit bien en dépit de ma haine, de mon amour parce que les passions se personnifient."*

En vertu de quoi, on pourrait effectivement dire que la locution *en dépit de* (et elle seule) a glissé.

Mais je préfère considérer qu'au lieu de glissement sémantique proprement dit, on assiste à une réduction de sens de la locution suite à la dépersonnalisation ayant accompagné sa grammaticalisation et, par là, l'extension de son emploi à des entités inanimées.